# Unable to flash official Indian JellyBean ROM on Samsung Galaxy Note GTN7000 SHV-E160l

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, updates, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note

I recently purchased a *Samsung Galaxy Note GTN7000.* When connected it to Kies it shows as galaxy note SHV-E160l.

I tried to flash Indian Samsung official JellyBean 4.1.2 update to it via ODIN. I have sufficient drivers (actually I went through a video tutorial). But ODIN shows fail.

When I bought this device it was running JellyBean 4.1.2, but I have serious heating issues, camera problems etc. That's why I decided to install official JellyBean. But failed.

How can I proceed and get it working?

```
Model number-gt-n7000
Base band version-N7000LXKJ8
Build number -JZO54.LXKJ8.F2A238.2JIA68
```

Comment: Maybe you [edit] your question and add some more details: Exact steps taken, exact error messages. In case you really just got an "update package", the reason might be easy: your device is already running the very same version, so the pre-conditions aren't met – and the update aborts to prevent failure.

Answer (score 0):

Infact your phone is not the international Note 1 GT-N700.
You have the korean version SHV-E160L which is converted to N700.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try out Heimdall? Unpack the package, select files and flash.

There are many video tutoritals about it.

My phone didn't work with Odin, I tried Heimdall and it didn't show any fail :)

Answer (score -2):

download root checker.. from the play store.. and then you will come to know your phone version.. if Korean or international version.. maybe you got cheated.. while buying.. or you didn't pay attention/check it out properly! if it is rooted you got no help with Samsung.. as far as I know.. but you can give it a try! and also leave the flashing to professionals! take it some mobile repair centre.. which you trust! :) hope it helps.. even I am getting heating issues on my SHV-E160L! :(